# Campo file não adiciona arquivos quando tem mais de um campo

Tags: jquery

Estou com problemas em um sistema de upload. O usuário poderá enviar até 05 arquivos, para isso, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<table border="0">
   <tr class='linhas'>
    <td>      
    <div class="md-group-add-on">  
      <span class="md-add-on-file">
          <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-upload fa-lg"></i> Arquivo</button>
      </span>
      <div class="md-input-file">
          <input type="file" name="Arquivo" class=""/>
          <input type="text" class="md-form-control md-form-file">
          <label class="md-label-file">Escolher Arquivo</label>
      </div>
       </div>
    </td>
    <td  style="padding: 5px"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td colspan="3"><button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-success" title="Adicionar mais arquivos"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais arquivos</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Como resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando o usuário clica em **Adicionar mais arquivos** no campo que foi adicionado, aparece o nome do arquivo que foi adicionado no primeiro campo, ou seja, ele replica o arquivo do primeiro campo, mas ao selecionar o arquivo do computador do segundo campo em diante, permanece o arquivo do primeiro campo. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Jquery está dessa forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
  $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
  $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
     if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
     }
  });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    if ($('.linhas').length < 5){
        novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
        novoCampo.find('input[type="file"]').val("");
        novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
        removeCampo();
     }else{
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#erro').modal('show');
      });
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Outro problema é que se eu colocar:

```
name="Arquivo"
```

Ele consegue adicionar ainda no primeiro campo, mas se eu renomear para:

```
name="Arquivo[]"
```

Não consigo adicionar mais arquivos em nenhum campo, nem no primeiro.

Comment: Reproduzi aqui o seu código e tudo funciona uma perfeição.

Comment: Também reproduzi.. fiz um fiddle pra testar.. só pra teste acrescentei um código para mudar o `name` dos inputs, mas não foi necessário, os `input` vem sem arquivo selecionado, pode ver aqui:  https://jsfiddle.net/tseam915/

Comment: Deve ser algum conflito que pode estar ocorrendo no projeto. Vou dar uma olhada aqui. Obrigado a todos.